# Yii: shared password for member's area

Tags: authentication, yii

What would be the best way to approach setting up a shared password protected area in Yii?

I am looking to have a view of a Group model, that can be accessed by a shared password created by the owner of that group - group members shouldn't have to log in, purely enter this passcode.

Should this still be done with Yii's built in auth tools? - or is there a simpler solution, bearing in mind that someone might want to access several groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using standard session mechanism built into PHP. When someone tries to view password-protected area, check the session variable, if the user haven't entered password yet then redirect him to some page with a password form (you can do the check using controller filters for example).

After the form is submitted, check correctness of password and if everything is ok, write it into the session. You can differentiate session keys by group ids.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [Yii filter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller#filter) capabilities to fire code before executing a controller action, and prevent actions that you do not want to allow.

I would create a common controller for all your group pages, and inherit other controller from this one if need to.

In the filter I would setup code to check/prompt for the password, and keep that in session.

For example we have a filter setup to detect if the user has accepted our revised Terms and Conditions. The filter will detect and will prevent access to the controller until the user doesn't confirm it.

```
class TocConfirmFilter extends CFilter {

    /**
     * Initializes the filter.
     * This method is invoked after the filter properties are initialized
     * and before {@link preFilter} is called.
     * You may override this method to include some initialization logic.
     */
    public function init() {

    }

    /**
     * Performs the pre-action filtering.
     * @param CFilterChain the filter chain that the filter is on.
     * @return boolean whether the filtering process should continue and the action
     * should be executed.
     */
    protected function preFilter($filterChain) {

        // do not perform this filter on this action
        if ($filterChain->action->controller->id . '/' . $filterChain->action->id == 'public/onePublicPage') {
            return true;
        }


        if (isset(Yii::app()->user->id)) {
            $user = user::model()->findbyPk(Yii::app()->user->id);
            if ($user === null)
                throw new CHttpException(404, 'The requested user does not exist.');
            if ($user->tocconfirmed == 0) {
                Yii::app()->getRequest()->redirect(Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('authorize/confirm'));
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Performs the post-action filtering.
     * @param CFilterChain the filter chain that the filter is on.
     */
    protected function postFilter($filterChain) {

    }

}
```